# Cloudbees Play 2 app control classpath order

Tags: playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1, cloudbees

I have a play 2 app which has a embedded vertx app. I need repos.txt and lands.properties in the classpath before vertx jar. I am using cloudebee. How can I control the classpath order to allow the jar which contains those two properties shows up earlier than vertx jar in the classpath?

Here is what vertx documentation says:
http://vertx.io/embedding_manual.html#config-files

*if you want to override any settings you can provide your own versions - just make sure you put them on the classpath ahead of the vert.x platform jar.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't control classpath ordering, it's computed as a list of file from lib folder (see [here](https://github.com/CloudBees-community/play2-clickstack/blob/master/functions#L59))